# Adding Values together in a loop with a dynamic Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

My current output in my foreach loop is this:

---

ID:21 Amount: 0.000
ID:1 Amount: 0.000
ID:2 Amount: 0.000
ID:3 Amount: 0.000
ID:5 Amount: 0.000
ID:8 Amount: 0.000

---

ID:1 Amount: 8.000
ID:5 Amount: 1.000
ID:17 Amount: 1.000

---

ID:1 Amount: 8.000
ID:5 Amount: 1.000
ID:17 Amount: 1.000

---

ID:1 Amount: 8.000
ID:5 Amount: 1.000
ID:17 Amount: 1.000

---

ID:1 Amount: 20.000
ID:5 Amount: 2.500
ID:17 Amount: 2.500

---

ID:21 Amount: 2.000
ID:1 Amount: 2.000
ID:2 Amount: 2.000
ID:3 Amount: 2.000
ID:4 Amount: 1.000
ID:19 Amount: 1.000

---

I want to Add together the "Amount" for each "ID" and output the totals for each "ID" at the end. The number of "ID"'s is dynamic. This is my current code:

```
$amount_for_that_group="0";
 foreach ($beneficiaryIDArray as $beneficiaryID) {
 //see what distribution group they belong to
  $query_ben_group= "SELECT * FROM `beneficiaries` WHERE `beneficiary_id`='$beneficiaryID'";

 $rs_ben_group=$conn->query($query_ben_group);

  if($rs_ben_group === false){                                                         trigger_error('SQL error:'.$query_ben_group.' Error: '.$conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);}
         else{

     while ($row_ben_group=$rs_ben_group->fetch_assoc()) {
          $ggroup=$row_ben_group['reward_group'];
          if ($ggroup==1) {
          $amount_for_that_group=$single_group1_amount;
          }
          if ($ggroup==2) {
          $amount_for_that_group=$single_group2_amount;
          }
          if ($ggroup==3) {
          $amount_for_that_group=$single_group3_amount;
          }

        }

      }           

echo "ID:$beneficiaryID Amount: $amount_for_that_group<br>";

 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't sum them in your query and then present the totals on your page?

Comment: They cannot be summed in the query. This query is the last of a series of calculations which determines both the ID and the Amount.

Comment: I tried creating an array and then using an if(in_array($beneficiaryID, $xarray){Add to the amount for that $beneficiaryID} else{array_push($xarray, $beneficiaryID, $amount_for_that_group) BUT I have not had success at all.